# Remove multiply:iron-router-progress log messages - Meteor 1.0

Tags: logging, meteor, iron-router

I recently installed the package `multiply:iron-router-progress` after I upgraded to the new `iron-router` package and Meteor 1.0. Now various log messages appear in my console:

```
[Log] IR:after (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:re-run (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:after (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:re-run (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:after (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:re-run (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:before (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Done (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Stop (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Reset (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Stop (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Stop (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:after (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:re-run (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:before (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Done (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Stop (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Reset (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Stop (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] Stop (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
[Log] IR:after (multiply_iron-router-progress.js, line 106)
```

How can I remove them?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also ran into this. I am sure that the author will take care of this real soon. For now, just don't use it till it's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

`upgraded multiply:iron-router-progress from version 1.0.0-pre2 to version 1.0.0`